# How to find row and col number of a cell in table

Tags: javascript, dom

Not using jQuery, what is the most efficient way of getting the Row and Col (X, Y) of a onClick even within a table?

I would think that assigning a click listener to just the table, and let it bubble to the top would work well, but really it just gives me the [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableElement). What I want to get from it is the Col number, and Row number from this one listener. Is that possible?

```
window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(this.tagName);
 }, false);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Get Cell Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998953/javascript-get-cell-location) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: @Felix, I did search, and none of the strings I used came up with that question. This should work quite a bit better for people using search later on as it uses more common terms.

Comment: Based on what Jonathan Sampson posted, I used this.
http://jsbin.com/iqavad/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could bind to the table, but that would leave open the possibility that you might click within the spacing between cells (which doesn't have a row or cell index). I have decided in the example below that I would bind to the cells themselves, and thus ensure I would always have a row and cell index.

```
var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var cls = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td");

function alertRowCell(e){
  var cell = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
  alert( cell.cellIndex + ' : ' + cell.parentNode.rowIndex );
}

for ( var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++ ) {
  if ( cls[i].addEventListener ) {
    cls[i].addEventListener("click", alertRowCell, false);
  } else if ( cls[i].attachEvent ) {
    cls[i].attachEvent("onclick", alertRowCell);
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/isedel/2/edit#javascript,html

I suppose you could safely bind to the table itself too, and perform a check against the source element to see if it was a cell or not:

```
var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

function alertRowCell (e) {
  var cell = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
  if ( cell.cellIndex >= 0 )
    alert( cell.cellIndex + ' : ' + cell.parentNode.rowIndex );
}

if ( tbl.addEventListener ) {
  tbl.addEventListener("click", alertRowCell, false);
} else if ( tbl.attachEvent ) {
  tbl.attachEvent("onclick", alertRowCell);
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/isedel/5/edit

Comment: Your second example (http://jsbin.com/isedel/4/edit#javascript,html) does not work for the first col. But my god, your on the right track!

Comment: @MarkTomlin Sorry about that. A `cellIndex` of `0` is falsy. Wasn't thinking right.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the most simple way to do that.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector('#myTable').onclick = function(ev) {
    var rowIndex = ev.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
    var cellIndex = ev.target.cellIndex;
    alert('Row = ' + rowIndex + ', Column = ' + cellIndex);
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>first row first column</td>
        <td>first row second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>second row first column</td>
        <td>second row second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>third row first column</td>
        <td>third row second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.target);
 }, false);
}
```