# Applying ng-click to a table column

Tags: html, angularjs

Is it possible to apply ng-click in AngularJS to a table column? I tried the following, which doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
<table> 
    <colgroup>
      <col ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="myFunction(item)"> </col>
    </colgroup>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item.title}} </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item.info}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: What is `colgroup`, directive? If yes, please post it, because in some cases custom directive may block ngClick invocation

Comment: @MaximShoustin, `<colgroup>` is a standard HTML table child tag for defining groups of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible do it in the way you have tried. You may register the ng-click on every td element. Another possibility may be registering the ng-click at the table element and use the original dom event to determin wich column was clicked. You can access the event in this way: ng-click="myFunction($event)" then in the controler:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(e){
   console.log(e);
}
```

see this post [How to find row and col number of a cell in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494661/how-to-find-row-and-col-number-of-a-cell-in-table) if you would like to go this way...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding ng-click to every td element, and it works just fine.