# Get the column number of a clicked column in a html table with duplicate headings using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, columnsorting

I use the javascript below to get the column number of a clicked column in a html table:

```
function sort(obj) {
    var th = obj.innerHTML;

    while (obj.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "TABLE") {
        obj = obj.parentNode
    }

    var table = document.getElementById(obj.id);
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var cols = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("th");

    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        if (cols[i].innerHTML == th) {
            var colNo = i;
            break
        }
    }

    alert(colNo);
    /*... and then I followed the procedure in sorting a table in
      https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp */
}
```

The table looks like this:

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick='sort(this)'>Field1_Name</th>
      <th onclick='sort(this)'>Field2_Name</th>
      <th onclick='sort(this)'>Field3_Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <!-- ... and so on -->
```

However, I cannot perfectly use the above script in a table that has duplicate innerHTML in the thead portion (please don't ask why). Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Cell Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998953/get-cell-location)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="sort(this)">Field1_Name</th>
      <th onclick="sort(this)">Field2_Name</th>
      <th onclick="sort(this)">Field3_Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>

  <script>
  function sort(obj) {
        var th = obj.cellIndex + 1;        
              alert(th);

    /*... and then I followed the procedure in sorting a table in
      https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp */
}
</script>
```

Comment: Problem solved with Tasos Fel's obj.cellIndex. I also learned rowNo = obj.parentNode.rowIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Combining w3's SortTable (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp) with Tasos Fel's reply, my javascript for sorting column of a html table now becomes:

```
function sort(obj) {
var n = obj.cellIndex, switching = true, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir = 'asc', switchcount = 0;
while (obj.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'TABLE') obj = obj.parentNode;
var rows = document.getElementById(obj.id).getElementsByTagName('tr');
while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[n];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName('td')[n];
        if (dir == 'asc') {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) { shouldSwitch= true; break; }
        } else {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) { shouldSwitch= true; break; }
        }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true; 
        switchcount ++;
    } else {
        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == 'asc') { dir = 'desc'; switching = true; }
    }
}
}
```

The 'Get Cell Location' topic here also taught me to get the row number and column number of any clicked cell of a html table as follows:

```
window.onload = function () {<br>
```

var cells = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td');
  for(var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].onclick = function() {
        var rowNo = this.parentNode.rowIndex + 1;
        var colNo = this.cellIndex + 1;
        alert("You clicked row " + rowNo + " column " + colNo);
    }
  }
}

I appreciate the quick reply. Thank you so much.