# How can I show a .gif while jQuery is processing other operations?

Tags: jquery

I would like to show a loader.gif file when the user clicks on a remove button the loader.gif is displayed then at the same time or the next step a table column is removed from view. The problem I have is that the loader.gif does not show until after the column is removed.

```
$(".removeButton").eq(i).click(function() {
  $('.loader').show(); // gif file is here
  
  let tbodyTrLength = $(".table-hideable tbody tr").length;
  
  for (let t = 0; t < tbodyTrLength; t++) {
    $(".table-hideable tbody tr").eq(t).find("td").eq(i).hide();
    $(".table-hideable thead tr:nth-child(2) th").eq(i).hide();
    $(".footer-restore-columns").removeClass("d-none");
  }
});
```

Comment: Are there CSS animations or something making the row removal slower than instantaneous? All this should happen immediately based on what you've shown. I'm not sure why you'd expect otherwise.

Comment: Protip: Just use `$(".table-hideable tbody tr").each(function() {...})` rather than your old-fashioned for loop.

Comment: Actually I don't think you need that loop anyway. You can run the three statements inside it bare (with modified selectors) and get the same outcome. It does nothing but create needless repetition.

Comment: @isherwood Each column has its own `removeButton` the idea was to allow multiple columns to be removed if desired. Please look at [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247375/jquery-add-button-to-table-heads). If there are multiple `removeButton` will your idea work?

Comment: You already have an index, so why would you need to loop over _all_ rows?

Comment: You haven't answered my first question. Is there an ajax call or something that causes a delay?

Comment: @isherwood there is no ajax. I am using a double header row so the 2nd header row has the same number of columns as the table body. So right now the removeButton is in the 2nd header.

Comment: @isherwood, I appreciate your question and comments. I was hoping that you would provide a detailed answer based on my question/comments and what you know.

Comment: I'm sure you would, but first I need to understand the problem. I still don't know what's causing a delay that would allow the image to appear for any length of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it under another thread using `setTimeout`. It won't be pretty because the main thread will be busy. You could do a timeout for every iteration of the loop.

Edit: being on the safe side, I've copied the `i` parameter into the inner function so it would be in the scope when the function runs.

```js
$(".removeButton").eq(i).click(function () {
  $('.loader').show(); // gif file is here

  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {

      let tbodyTrLength = $(".table-hideable tbody tr").length;
      for (let t = 0; t < tbodyTrLength; t++) {
        $(".table-hideable tbody tr").eq(t).find("td").eq(i).hide();
        $(".table-hideable thead tr:nth-child(2) th").eq(i).hide();
        $(".footer-restore-columns").removeClass("d-none");
      }

    }, 1)
  })(i);

});
```

Comment: What problem does this solve? There's apparently no delay to row removal.

Comment: It's a technique for making a ui change before the main thread gets busy. It might be relevant if there are 1000's of elements to hide.

Comment: Fair, but the loop is pointless here. The statements inside can be run on their own and achieve the same results. That may completely negate the need for a spinner.

Comment: @ITgoldman, Thank you for your answer. Do you happen to know how isherwood is indicating to change the code to make it faster? Do you think he is right and that it is do able logically?

Comment: I don't think @isherwood is suggesting to change the code to make it faster. But maybe it's possible. Just for example, the line `$(".footer-restore-columns").removeClass("d-none");` shouldn't be inside the loop since it doesn't depend on `t`. Same goes for `$(".footer-restore-columns").removeClass("d-none");`. Actually also the first line can be re-written to be outside of the loop.